# Android toast doesn't show on UI for some reason

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm doing similar to what discussed here:
[Android BroadcastReceiver within Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555215/android-broadcastreceiver-within-activity)

I have application that runs with or without UI. When screen is off it's just working on background. When UI is on and visible - I would like to let user know that something just happened.

So, I followed samples in topic above and registered broadcast receiver on my `Activity`. I register `onResume` and unregister on `onPause`

```
private BroadcastReceiver uiNeedToBeUpdatedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    };

@Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();

        // TODO: Unregister broadcast receiver
        unregisterReceiver(uiNeedToBeUpdatedReceiver);
    }

@Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();

        // TODO: Register for broadcast events
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("com.my.uineedtobeupdated");
        registerReceiver(uiNeedToBeUpdatedReceiver, filter);
```

Inside my `AsyncTask` that runs on background I do this:

```
// Send broadcast - if UI active it will see it:
        Intent broadcast = new Intent();
        broadcast.setAction("com.my.uineedtobeupdated");
        MyApplication.Me.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
```

Well, everyting works. I get broadcasts and I see in my debugger that I'm hitting line where Toast should show. But I don't see any toast popping up.

Is that threading issue? I though if I receive broadcast it shuld be on UI thread? Why do I observe this behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's important not only to create the Toast, but actually display it. The easy way:

```
Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You can also, of course:

```
Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
myToast.show();
```

Comment: @katit: The emphasis being on the `show()` that you are missing.

Answer (score 2):

```
Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

You are making a `Toast`, but you are not showing it. You need to call `show` on it, like this:

```
Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```