# Using a broadcast receiver and getcontentresolver() to build a callerID

Tags: java, android, debugging, static-methods

I'm trying to setup a simple caller ID for a messaging application I'm creating for learning purposes.  I'm having trouble using the ContactsContact content provider to do this.  here is the problem:

I am running into this Error:

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method updateMessageBox() from the type MainActivity

The simplest fix would be to make updateMessageBox() a static method.  However, I can't make updateMessageBox() a static method because it implements getContentResolver(), which cannot be used in a static method.  I think I'm having some trouble understanding the static/non-static declaration (obviously).  Here is the MainActivity Class and the SmsReceiver Class.  I won't include the Android Manifest file but I will note that it does have the SmsReceiver file registered to receive SMS.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Button btnSendSMS;
public String recipient = "phone Number was here and it worked";
public static String callerId;
public static String message;
public String sender = "Jeff";
static TextView textView;
public static String LOGTAG = "LOGGED";




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);






    btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        final EditText textInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final String  str=textInput.getText().toString();
        sendSMS(recipient, str);
        textInput.setText("");
        textView.append("\n" + sender + ": " + str);

    }
    });
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{String SENT = "SMS SENT";
String DELIVERED = "SMS DELIVERED";
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
new Intent(SENT), 0);
PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new 

Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    switch (getResultCode())
    {
    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS DELIVERED",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "GENERIC FAILURE",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NO SERVICE",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NULL PDU",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "RADIO OFF",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    }
    }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));
    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    switch (getResultCode())
    {
    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Delivered",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Not Delivered",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    }
    }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);

    }


    public void updateMessageBox()
    {


        Cursor contactLookupCursor =  
                   getContentResolver().query(
                            Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, 
                            Uri.encode(callerId)), 
                            new String[] {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup._ID}, 
                            null, 
                            null, 
                            null);
                try {
                    while(contactLookupCursor.moveToNext()){
                        String contactName = contactLookupCursor.getString(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String contactId = contactLookupCursor.getString(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup._ID));
                        Log.d(LOGTAG, "contactMatch name: " + contactName);
                        Log.d(LOGTAG, "contactMatch id: " + contactId);
                        if (contactName != null) {
                            callerId = contactName;
                        } 
                        }
                    } finally {
                        textView.append("\n" + callerId + ": " + message);
                    contactLookupCursor.close();
                    } 


            }


      }
```

And the SmsReceiver file

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();

    Object[] messages=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] sms=new SmsMessage[messages.length];

    for(int n=0;n<messages.length;n++){
        sms[n]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
    }

    for(SmsMessage msg:sms){
        MainActivity.callerId = msg.getOriginatingAddress();
        MainActivity.message = msg.getMessageBody();
        MainActivity.updateMessageBox();
    }
}
```

}

Any tips pointing me the right direction would be very much appreciated.  I've been workin on this for a few days and Its driving me nuts.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a concrete `MainActivity` *instance* to call `updateMessageBox()`.

Ether start a new activity (or display a notification, or toast, or different) when the broadcast is recived, or your activity should register a reciver in its `onResume()` method, and unregister it in its `onPause()` method. The first way would mean your application recives all SMS messages, the second way would mean that messages are ignored while the user is not within your activity. Which method you wish to choose depends on your application.

Especially for the second option, see [a related question about BroadcastRecivers within Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555215/android-broadcastreceiver-within-activity).

Comment: Thank you.  This helps point me in the right direction.  I really wasn't thinking about the android lifecycle like I should have been.